# admin_post in object oriented plugin

Tags: forms

i try to write my plugin object oriented. Now, I have a problem.

The admin_post action don't run. I'm posting the code, where I localize the problem.

```
   class install
   {
        $admin = new sm_admin();
        add_menu_page( 'Social Media', 'Social Media', 'read', SM_CUSTOMPOSTTYPE, array( $admin, 'ms_get_socialmedia_page' ), '', 22 );
   }

   class sm_admin
   {
       function __construct()
        {
            add_action( 'admin_post_change_socialmedia', array( &$this, 'ms_change_socialmedia' ) );
        }

        function ms_get_socialmedia_page() {
                    ?>
                    <form action="<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-post.php' ); ?>" method="post">
                        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="change_socialmedia">
                        .
                        .
                        .
                        .
                        <?php echo get_submit_button('Speichern'); ?>
                        </form>
        <?php       
                }

                function ms_change_socialmedia() {
                    //save everything + redirect
                }
    }
```

It only refere to admin.php. ms_change_socialmedia will not called. Somewhere an error?

Comment: None of your classes/objects are initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build this in to just one class.

Obviously change the method names to anything you wish, these are just the ones I use in my plugins.

You'll notice that I've also added a couple of sanity checks - one is designed to stop people accessing your plugin page directly (i.e. before the core files have been loaded), and the other is to prevent access to the `on_save_settings` method from anywhere other than your admin page.

I should also point you towards the [**Writing a Plugin** Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin), which has lots of examples and can direct you to further reference material to help you with this process.

Finally, I'd recommend also looking in to the [**Settings API**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API). It's not a silver bullet, but it can make managing plugin settings much easier.

```
/**
 * Avoid direct calls to this file where WP core files are not present
 */
if(!function_exists('add_action')) :
    header('Status: 403 Forbidden');
    header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
    exit();
endif;

$sm_admin = new SM_Admin();
class SM_Admin{

    /** Constructor */
    function __construct(){

        add_action('admin_menu', array(&$this, 'on_admin_menu'));                           // Add the admin menu
        add_action('admin_post_change_socialmedia', array( &$this, 'on_save_settings'));    // Save any changes

    }

    /**
     * Add the admin menu
     */
    function on_admin_menu(){

        add_menu_page( 'Social Media', 'Social Media', 'read', SM_CUSTOMPOSTTYPE, array( &$this, 'on_show_page' ), '', 22 );

    }  

    /**
     * Render the page
     */
    function on_show_page(){
?>
        <form action="<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-post.php' ); ?>" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="change_socialmedia">
            <!-- { Your form... } -->
            <?php wp_nonce_field('ms_change_socialmedia', 'ms_nonce'); ?>
            <?php echo get_submit_button('Speichern'); ?>
        </form>
<?php      
    }

    /**
     * Save the settings
     */
    function on_save_settings(){

        if(!isset( $_POST['ms_nonce']) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['ms_nonce'], 'ms_change_socialmedia')) :
            wp_die(new WP_Error(
                'invalid_nonce', __('Sorry, I\'m afraid you\'re not authorised to do this.')
            ));
            exit;
        endif;

        echo '<pre>'; print_r($_POST); echo '</pre>';
        die('Hey, it works!  You can now edit the \'on_save_settings\' method to sanitize and save your settings as you require.');

        wp_redirect($_POST['_wp_http_referer']);

    }

}
```